# ListBox MultiSelect Drag and Drop problem

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox

I'm trying to do a drag and drop of multiple items between ListBox in windows forms. The problem I'm having is if I select multiple items holding the Shift key and try to drag and drop it without release the the key I get an error. Actually the SelectedIndices and SelectedItems just show 1 item, the one I clicked first, even though multiple items are highlighted in the ListBox.

I'm using SelectionMode = MultiExtended

```
void ZListBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDraggingPoint.HasValue && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        var pointToClient = PointToClient(MousePosition);

        if (isDraggingPoint.Value.Y != pointToClient.Y)
        {
            lastIndexItemOver = -1;
            isDraggingPoint = null;

            var dropResult = DoDragDrop(SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that if I don't release the left mouse button before I do "DoDragDrop", the items aren't selected and also if I try to get the SelectedIndices from the other ListBox, the Count is the number of "selected items", but when I try to navigate the list, I get a IndexOutOfRangeException.

[image]

Is there any work around for it?

Sample code to reproduce the issue:
(To reproduce:
1- Select an item
2- Hold shift and click in another item, than without release shift and mouse button, drag this item (if you have a breakpoint inside the 'if', you'll see just 1 item on SelectedItems))

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var someList = new List<ListItemsTest>();
            someList.Add(new ListItemsTest() { ID = 1, Name = "Name 1" });
            someList.Add(new ListItemsTest() { ID = 2, Name = "Name 2" });
            someList.Add(new ListItemsTest() { ID = 3, Name = "Name 3" });
            someList.Add(new ListItemsTest() { ID = 4, Name = "Name 4" });
            someList.Add(new ListItemsTest() { ID = 5, Name = "Name 5" });
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
            listBox1.DataSource = someList;
            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
            listBox1.MouseMove += ListBox1_MouseMove;
            listBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        void ListBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                var dropResult = DoDragDrop(listBox1.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }

        public class ListItemsTest
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the SelectedIndex and SelectedItems values?  Which line throws the error?  Document all that.

Comment: @LarsTech When I'm getting SelectedItems on MouseMove, there is only 1 item. When I'm in the other ListBox and try to get ListBox1.SelectedItems I get the error

Comment: the problem is that before I even start the drag and drop the SelectedItems is wrong, it never select the items if I don't release the mouse button

Comment: I've added an image

Comment: I edited the code that was already there

Comment: It's in the own ListBox, the one I selected the items, at this point I didn't start the drag and drop yet

Comment: you could override the component, you could use Listbox1 in front, the result is the same.. I added a sample code

Comment: To reproduce:
- Select an item
- Hold shift and click in another item, than without release shift and mouse button, drag this item (if you have a breakpoint inside the 'if', you'll see just 1 item on SelectedItems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let you know I found another solution. If I set Capture = false in the MouseDown event, Items will work as expected and we don't need to do the manual selection.

Eg:

```
void ZListBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Capture = false;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Another example, in case you need to know what Items were selected in a ListBox, using the SHIFT key to create an extended selection, even if you don't need to initiate a `Draq&Drop` operation:

Using the data sample you provided in the question, a **List**.

In the example, a `List<int>` (**`lbSelectedIndexes`**) is used to keep track of what items are currently selected in the ListBox. This List is filled only when the selection is performed using the `SHIFT` key, or after a Drag&Drop operation is initiated. This can be useful to determine the type of selection.

In all other cases the `List<int>` is empty and the `SelectedItems` and `SelectedIndices` collections can be used to determine the items currently selected.

The [SystemInformation.DragSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.dragsize) value is also used to determine if the drag operation should be initiated when the Mouse Pointer is moved while the Left Button is pressed.
When the Drag&Drop operation is started, a new [DataObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject.-ctor) is filled with ListBox Items corresponding to the current selection, no matter how the selection was performed.
The [DragDropEffects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects) is set to **`DragDropEffects.Copy`**.

```
Point lbMouseDownPosition = Point.Empty;
List<int> lbSelectedIndexes = new List<int>();

private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var lb = sender as ListBox;
    lbMouseDownPosition = e.Location;
    lbSelectedIndexes = new List<int>();
    int idx = lb.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && idx != lb.SelectedIndex) {
        lbSelectedIndexes.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(
            Math.Min(idx, lb.SelectedIndex),
            Math.Abs((idx - lb.SelectedIndex)) + 1).ToArray());
    }
}

private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && 
        ((Math.Abs(e.X - lbMouseDownPosition.X) > SystemInformation.DragSize.Width) || 
         (Math.Abs(e.Y - lbMouseDownPosition.Y) > SystemInformation.DragSize.Height)))
    {
        var lb = sender as ListBox;
        DataObject obj = new DataObject();
        if (lbSelectedIndexes.Count == 0) {
            lbSelectedIndexes = lb.SelectedIndices.OfType<int>().ToList();
        }
        List<object> selection = lb.Items.OfType<object>().Where((item, idx) =>
            lbSelectedIndexes.IndexOf(idx) >= 0).ToList();
        obj.SetData(typeof(IList<ListItemsTest>), selection);

        lb.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

To test the results, drop another ListBox (**`listBox2`**, here) on the Form, set its `AlloDrop` property to `true` and subscribe to the **`DragEnter`** and **`DragDrop`** events.

When the Mouse Pointer enters the second ListBox client area, the `DragDropEffects.Copy` effect is triggered if the [e.Data.GetDataPresent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.idataobject.getdatapresent) method detects that the dragged object contains a **`List<ListItemsTest>`**.

If the Data format is accepted, the Data Object is *transformed* back to a `List<ListItemsTest>` - using the [IDataObject.GetData()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.idataobject.getdata) method - and set as the `DataSource` of `listBox2`.

```
private void listBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    if (e.Data != null && e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IList<ListItemsTest>))) {
        lb.DisplayMember = "Name";
        lb.ValueMember = "ID";
        lb.DataSource = e.Data.GetData(typeof(IList<ListItemsTest>));
    }
}

private void listBox2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IList<ListItemsTest>))) {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see the issue now. The funny thing is, pressing the Ctrl key to select items in the list works normal, but the Shift key doesn't.  My solution would be to recreate your own SelectedItems collection:

```
void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
    int mouseIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (mouseIndex > -1) {
      ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection x = new ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(listBox1);
      if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) {
        int i1 = Math.Min(listBox1.SelectedIndex, mouseIndex);
        int i2 = Math.Max(listBox1.SelectedIndex, mouseIndex);
        for (int i = i1; i <= i2; ++i) {
          x.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
      } else {
        x = listBox1.SelectedItems;
      }
      var dropResult = DoDragDrop(x, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a ListBox that I wanted to be drag and drop sortable, and also have extended multiselect.  I was getting the same issue as the OP, where the selected items was bombing out when using shift+click to select the items.  If I add in a check to make sure no modifier keys are pressed on mouse down before initiating the DoDragDrop, it solves the problem.

(this is a VB.net code snippet, but you get the idea)

```
Private Sub lbClasses_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lbClasses.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso Control.ModifierKeys = 0 Then
        If Not IsNothing(lbClasses.SelectedItem) Then
            lbClasses.DoDragDrop(lbClasses.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```