# Allow drag-select in a ListBox?

Tags: winforms

I have a System.Windows.Form.ListBox with about 150 items in it. Is there a way to enable drag-select? I'm trying various settings, but nothing seems to change it - I can select multiple lines by clicking on them, but only one-by-one.

Comment: [Winforms ListBox multiselect Drag and Drop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54430120/7444103).

Comment: Nice Q/A - however, here it seems the OP is looking for drag-selection and not drag and drop. If he enable drag-and drop, then drag-selection will be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`SelectionMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to `MultiExtended`.

This way you can select multiple items by dragging mouse, as well using SHIFT, CTRL, and arrow keys to make selections.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It was that "Extended" that I was not looking at.