# Problem with Mouse Up event in ListBox .NET Framework

Tags: c#, listbox, selection, mouseup

I have got a problem with ListBox control in Visual Studio 2019 C# Windows Form Application. What I didn't like in the original control is that the element is selected on mouse down. It was a problem when I wanted to drag and drop because when I have multiple items selected and I want to drag the selection, the event I click is selecting off. What I wnated to do is to remember which item was selected off, then select it on again in mouse down event. Then I wanted to force the selection off if after mouse up event the mouse cursor is still on the selected item. It works fine only if it is about one item selection. When more than one item is selected, the mouse up event is not called. Anyone knows how to manage that problem?

Comment: [ListBox MultiSelect Drag and Drop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54430120/7444103) (not the self-accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. It turned out that when the DoDragDrop method is called the MouseUp doesn't work properly. So I call it only when the cursor is minimum 30 pixel from the MouseDown cursor coordinates and it works fine now.